# Run exe from powershell and output the stream to the same console

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have an application which can be called from PowerShell. It uses an argument as a set of instructions. Everything is working fine however I would like to keep the messages in the same window, as when this is called it opens a new window and the original ps console will not get any output.

I have already tried the following code. It opens up a new window, on the new window I can see the output text. Also the file out.txt is generated but not populated.

```
    $execFile = “C:\Program Files\DBBest\Database Compare Suite\DBBest.DataSuite.Console.exe”
$params = "C:\SchemaSync1.xml"


Start-Process -FilePath $execFile -NoNewWindow -wait -ArgumentList $params -RedirectStandardError error.txt -RedirectStandardOutput out.txt -ErrorAction Continue
```

I also tried the calling this Csharp class but I still opened a new window and never got the output in the original ps console.

```
$psi = New-object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo

$psi.CreateNoWindow = $true
$psi.UseShellExecute = $false
$psi.RedirectStandardOutput = $true
$psi.RedirectStandardError = $true
$psi.FileName = 'C:\Program Files\DBBest\Database Compare Suite\DBBest.DataSuite.Console.exe'
$psi.Arguments = "C:\SchemaSync1.xml"
$psi.LoadUserProfile = $true

$process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$process.StartInfo = $psi

[void]$process.Start()

$output = $process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
$process.WaitForExit()
$output
```

The reason I would like to have the output is to automate this process on a build agent and I could catch any errors.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `& $execfile $params`?

Answer (score 0):

If it's opening a new console on its own like this, you're probably not going to see the data there in powershell unless it specifically returns that data to stdout. Here's some other things you can try though:

You can try sending all output streams to standard output:

```
Start-Process $execFile $params *>&1
```

You could try running it as a powershell job - Job objects capture each output stream separately, and capture output for child processes as well:

```
$job = Start-Job -Name Foo -ScriptBlock {Start-Process $execFile $params}
Wait-Job $job

# check for any child jobs (and check these for child jobs too, depending on your process):
$job.ChildJobs.Name

# check job or child job(s) for any output. This just formats warning and errors nicely:
[pscustomobject] @{
  Information = $job.Information
  Warning     = $job.Warning.Message
  Error       = $job.Error.Exception.Message
  Output      = $job.Output
} | 
Format-List
```

You may have better luck checking out the `DBBest.DataSuite.Console.exe.config` file for better logging options or maybe some kind of `-verbose` flag you can run the program with.